# Submodule triggers a build

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to do the following in Jenkins

- A submodule gets updated and triggers a build where the main project gets cloned and the tests are run on the main project.
- I then want to CD into the submodule directory, checkout master, and pull the latest

How can I create a Jenkins build so that an update to the submodule triggers a build of the main project?

So let's say I have a main project with submodules A and B, when A gets updated, it triggers a build for the main project, where the main project gets cloned and tests are run on the main project

Comment: An update of the submodule in your git checkout should be done by a commit as usual, so you could trigger your build as usual.

A submodule is always pinned to a certain commit id in your "main" repository. To change that pin, a commit is needed.